# CGAL Quadratic Programming Solver, how to enter "x^4" in objective function? and in the constraints?

Tags: c++, exponent, cgal, quadratic

I am trying to minimize a function like the following:

```
a*x^4+b*y
```

and constraints like:

```
x^2 <= a
```

in [CGAL::Quadratic_program](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/QP_solver/Chapter_main.html#Section_10.3).

To input "x^2" in the objective function I can do the following:

```
qp.set_d(X, X, 2);
```

but what about "x^4" ?

To add a constraint like "x<=a":

```
hp.set_a(X, 0, 1);
hp.set_b(0, a);
```

but what about "x^2 <= a" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to solve this

[image]

kind of problems is to modify the objective function and constraints, in this case by setting z^2 = z.

```
        //>=
        Program hp(CGAL::LARGER, false, 0, false, 0);
        //x+y >= -4
        hp.set_a(X, 0, 1); hp.set_a(Y, 0, 1);
        hp.set_b(0, -4);
        //4x+2y+z^2 >= -a*b
        //z^2 = z
        hp.set_a(X, 1, 4); hp.set_a(Y, 1, 2); hp.set_a(Z, 1, 1);
        hp.set_b(1, -a * b);
        //-x + y >= −1
        hp.set_a(X, 2, -1); hp.set_a(Y, 2, 1);
        hp.set_b(2, -1);
        //x <= 0
        hp.set_a(X,3,1);
        hp.set_b(3,0);
        hp.set_r(3,CGAL::SMALLER);
        //y <= 0
        hp.set_a(Y,4,1);
        hp.set_b(4,0);
        hp.set_r(4,CGAL::SMALLER);
        //objective function
        //min a*x^2 + b*y + z^4
        //z^2 = z
        //min a*x^2 + b*y + z^2
        hp.set_d(X, X, 2 * a); //2D
        hp.set_c(Y, b);
        hp.set_d(Z, Z, 2); //2D

        // solve the program
        Solution s = CGAL::solve_quadratic_program(hp, ET());
        assert(s.solves_quadratic_program(hp));
```

Answer (score 1):

From the given link:

> This package lets you solve convex *quadratic* programs of the general
>   form ...

Why did you decide you can use *quadratic* solver to solve your power-of-four polynomial? Quadratic doesn't stand for "quadra" as a "four", it stands for a square as a "quadragon" and means power-of-two.

In short: you cannot use this tool to solve your problem.

Comment: either using a linear or a quadratic program this can be done. [this](http://i.imgur.com/JufkE.png) is the actual optimization problem I have to solve using CGAL.

Comment: I guess the trick is to set z=z^2 and solve a*x^2+b*y+z^2, then find the result using sqrt(z). Problem is that for instance with a=32 b=-9 I get "infeasible" while the solution should be 82944.. mh.

Comment: @fusio If you think this is a bug, please report in on the cgal-discuss mailing list.